# Ajax filtering a Drupal 7 View

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a View where i would like to expose filters to permit the user to customize the view output.
I know i can use exposed filters but, instead of a drop down (or checkbox/radiobutton of exposed filters) i want to put a list of DIV or LI that, when clicked, can update the view output through ajax. In which way is it possible using Views 3 and Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Better exposed filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module to change output of your filter items to links. And Use AJAX option in Advanced settings of a view to make filtering ajaxifyed.